# How to collapse/hide dropdown submenu

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, ng-hide

I am trying to hide my dropdown submenu after a user makes a selection.  I want it to end up looking like `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>`

Below is some code I have started but cannot figure out how to hide the menu.  Thanks.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">2014<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="">Q1</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="">Q2</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="">Q3</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="">Q4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="btn-group bt-toggle">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="toggleFilters();">Select Year</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="caret"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </button>
       </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd wrap whatever is in the ".dropdown-submenu" in a div and do something like:

```
$("#newdiv").hide()
$("#newdiv").animate({height: '0px'}, "slow");
$(".dropdown-submenu").append("<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger\"></span>");
```

Or, have the span there, hidden, and showing it.. so instead, you'd have

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger aspan" style="display:none;"></span>
      <div id="newdiv">

        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">2014<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="">Q1</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="">Q2</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="">Q3</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="">Q4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="btn-group bt-toggle">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="toggleFilters();">Select Year</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="caret"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </button>
       </div>
     </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

AND JS:

```
$("#newdiv").hide();
$("#newdiv").animate({height: '0px'}, "slow");
$(".aspan").show();
```

EDIT:  animate should go to 0, and span should be before the #newdiv